# Проблема при отправке запроса на сайт через библиотеку requests

Tags: python, парсер, proxy, request

**Код:**

```
import requests
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

proxies = {"http" : "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050", "https" : "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050", "socks5" : "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"}

for i in range(60):
    r = requests.get("https://synapsenet.ru/search/subcategoryinregion/moskva/bitovaya-elektrotehnika/bitovaya-tehnika?page="+str(i), headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().random)}, proxies=proxies)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
```

При его выполнении получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)   File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without" http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)   File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without" urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "BotMainPart.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get("https://synapsenet.ru/search/subcategoryinregion/moskva/bitovaya-elektrotehnika/bitovaya-tehnika?page="+str(i), headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().random)}, proxies=proxies)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

**Вопрос:**
Как исправить данную ошибку?

**Ps:** Пытаюсь решить проблему уже 2 суток, но ничего не получается.

Comment: прокси на машине поднято?

Comment: да, tor proxy. С другими сайтами такой проблемы нет

Comment: Попробовал запустить ваш скрипт - то работает, то выдает эту ошибку. Перезапуск тора помогает на некоторое время. Подозреваю, что на сайте какая-то защита от ботов.

Comment: @Andrey с этим можно что-то сделать? Что выдаёт в этом скрипте бота?

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что когда вы делаете запросы, то каждый раз генерируете новый User-Agent, но при этом IP адрес прокси остается неизменным. Я бы попробовал перезапустить тор,  выбрать один фиксированный User-Agent и не делать запросы слишком часто (например, в интервале от 5 до 10 секунд).

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Попробуйте: pip install -U requests[socks]

Comment: @FedotSoldier  soks5 у меня установлен, так что дело не в нём

Comment: @СергейАндреев промежутки временные между запросами пробовали ставить? time.sleep()